# Intent created but the startActivity method didn't identify

Tags: android, android-cardview

I tried to set an Onclick event for my cardView. As you can see, I created that event inside the OnBindViewHolder but the problem is that the startActivity method didn't identify.What do you think i should do? Thank you in advance and sorry for my English :)

```
public class AdapterVRList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterVRList.CourseViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<DObjectVrList> DObjectVrListList;

public AdapterVRList(Context context, List<DObjectVrList> DObjectVrListList){
    this.context = context;
    this.DObjectVrListList = DObjectVrListList;
}
public AdapterVRList(Context context){

}


@Override
public CourseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_vr,parent,false);
    return new CourseViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CourseViewHolder holder, int position) {

    DObjectVrList DObjectVrList = DObjectVrListList.get(position);
    holder.CourseText.setText(DObjectVrList.getTitleCourse());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CourseInnerPage course = new CourseInnerPage(getItemCount());
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,CourseInnerPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 8;
}

public class CourseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView CourseText;

    public CourseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        CourseText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_text);
    }
}
}
```

**The error is: Cannot resolve the startActivity method**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your adapter or its superclasses do not have the method `startActivity()`.

Use `context.startActivity();`

Comment: OK, but i have to wait 10 minutes, you know.

Answer (score 0):

use context.startActivity(intent)